What writing system are they using in "In the Land of Leadale"?
What language or writing system are the characters using in the anime, "In the Land of Leadale"?
For Example:



Is it just a made up language and writing system or is it based off of any existing language and writing system?

They just use English letters to write Romaji, but everything is rotated 90° and you read from bottom to top.
At the end of each paper it says for example "Boukensha Girudo" (Adventurer Guild), but they use a version of romanization where sha is written as sya.

The beginning says "Iraisho" (written request).
Under the rectangle with the request it says: "Houshuu: Ginka: 1" (Reward: 1 silver coin)
